# ASP.NET Core Refit Client for RESTful API: How to divide clients

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, refit

I'm currently building a client for a RESTful API with ASP.NET Core 5 and Refit (using HttpClientFactory). What I'm a little confused about, is how to divide the API interfaces (how many separate interfaces to write for different API endpoints/ressources).

Let's say we have an API with the following endpoints, each with a few subroutes (e.g. .../{id} or .../{id}/pets) and/or different HTTP verbs: **http://myhost/api/customers** and **http://myhost/api/employees**

What's the best practice here, writing one interface `IMyHostApi` which covers the whole API? Or is it better to divide this into something like `IMyHostCustomersApi` and `IMyHostEmployeesApi` and then add multiple Refit clients with the correspinding base addresses?

for context, the client(s) will be added like this:

```
services
    .AddRefitClient<IGitHubApi>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com"));
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO best way to use Refit may be by splitting logical interfaces and then inherit from them in one host interface that will be resolved with HttpClientFactory.

```cs
public interface IGithubApi : IAuthenticationApi, ICustomerApi, IEmployeesApi {}
```

```cs
services
    .AddRefitClient<IGitHubApi>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com"));
```

Beauty of this is in **simplicity and versatility**. You can still attach different headers to different interfaces.

```cs
[Headers("X-Header: A")]
public interface IAuthenticationApi {}

[Headers("X-Header: B")]
public interface ICustomerApi {}
```

In DI you can cast it into desired inferface for cleaner IntelliSense:

```cs
private readonly IEmployeesApi employeesApi;

public AuthenticationService(IGithubApi employeesApi)
{
    this.employeesApi = employeesApi;
}
```

You can also detect in which interface currently called endpoint resides in from inside `DelegatingHandler` for some advanced routing etc.

```cs
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var restMethodInfo = (RestMethodInfo)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageOptions.RestMethodInfo];
    var iface = restMethodInfo.HostingType; // MyCompany.MyApiClient.IEmployeesApi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to have all endpoints in one huge interface you can use this Refit feature - https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#interface-inheritance.

In that case, your base interface will be derived from your splitted interfaces and you will have one entry point for your API. And all endpoints will be logically splitted into separate interfaces

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interface inheritance does not really apply to my question though. I don't have any API endpoints I want to share across multiple services/interfaces. My question is if it makes sense to define multiple interfaces for different API endpoints / REST resources with the same base URL. From the example in the link it seems like this is a practice though, so I think I'll split up my interfaces based on their usage.

Comment: This does not answer what the OP has asked in the first place